# Running aspnet core as a service - nssm vs RunAsService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nginx-reverse-proxy, nssm

I'm looking at the documentation for ASP.NET Core, under "Host in a Windows service" it says :

> The recommended way to host an ASP.NET Core app on Windows without using IIS is to run it in a Windows Service.

Then it proceeds to give an example which requires starting the WebHost using "RunAsService()". I'm currently using "Run()".

I'm already deploying my app to Linux using nginx and a service. My initial plans to deploy on Windows (before reading the documentation) was to use nginx and create a service using NSSM and make no changes to my code.

Are there any reasons to avoid nginx+an nssm created service and prefer the dotnet core provided way of running Kestrel as a service ?

I don't think it changes anything but this aspnet app is a REST API, no actual web page, and will always be reached thru a proxy on my Angular website running on Apache/IIS/Nginx. In my dev settings, i'm running a single nginx instance with two servers and proxy_pass from my Website to my REST API.